# Problema en ejecución de java

Tags: java, eclipse

a la hora de ejecutar un proyecto en mi eclipse me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Access restriction: The type SAXException is not accessible due to 
restriction on required library /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk- 
amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Parece que no tienes acceso a la jdk, has probado con alguna otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tambien puedes ir a la configuración Build Path en las propiedades del proyecto y eliminar la JRE System Library.

Luego la vuelves a añadir con Add library y así se resetea. Posiblemente se trate de un problema de versiones de JRE, tener varias instaladas en el sistema, y que no se seleccione la correcta.

Comment: Vale solucionado. Se eliminan todas las librerias y se deja solamente JRE System Library

Comment: También puede ser porque el propio proyecto usa una librería que ya incluye esa clase y por algún motivo ha adquirido más preferencia. En cualquier caso la solución sigue siendo la misma